# In SkLearn's Random Forests, why is ```max_samples == None``` by default?

Tags: correlation, random-forest

***The more uncorrelated*** are the trees with each other, ***the better the results*** a Random Forest ensemble may get.
Sources: [Nvidia](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/glossary/data-science/random-forest/), [Tutorial by Tony Yiu](https://towardsdatascience.com/understanding-random-forest-58381e0602d2)

According to [the official documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html), the hyperparameter `max_samples` will take the value of `None` unless otherwise specified. This means, the whole input sample will be used every time to train every single estimator.

Is this value by default of `max_samples`, *supposed to be an advantage* over a value between 0 and 1?

Let's say, for example, `max_samples` was 0.7 by default. **Wouldn't that produce more uncorrelated trees, resulting thus in better models?**

Any contribution is well appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Less correlated, but also less accurate (because trained on a smaller sample size), trees... as with most things, it's a tradeoff.

Comment: @jbowman Remember, trees are _not_ required to be _individually_ accurate, but different from each other. That's exactly the way Random Forests are meant to work.
But thanks for your point though 

Comment: Yes, but if each tree is less accurate in one setup than the other, that offsets  (to some extent) reduced correlation between them.   Think of 100 completely uncorrelated trees, each with MSE 1000, compared to 100 identical (perfectly correlated) trees, each with MSE 1.  Which ensemble will be the better predictor?

Answer (score 2):

According to that linked documentation, `max_samples` is the number of bootstrap samples to draw

> If `bootstrap` is `True`, the number of samples to draw from X to train each base estimator.

So, taking $n$ equal to the sample size means a *bootstrap* sample of size $n$. It *does not* mean that the whole sample is used in every tree.  About 63% of the sample will be used in each tree, with some observations used twice or three times or more.

Comment: Alright, so then again, how is this supposed to impact in the correlation among the many trees?